# Eloquent + Objeto carregando a si próprio

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Sempre utilizei muito bem o Eloquent com os métodos estáticos. Ontem, ao criar um novo conceito de registro de sessão para um novo projeto, me deparei com uma dúvida que não consegui esclarecer.

Tenho um modelo "Sessao" que aponta pra uma tabela com o mesmo nome no banco de dados. Acontece que no momento em que o usuário passa o token, um objeto da classe "Sessao" é criado e o seu construtor tenta buscar o registro relacionado a aquele token no banco de dados. Usualmente eu utilizaria:

```
$sessao = Sessao::where('token',Input::get('token'))->get();
```

Ou algo assim:

```
$this->where('token',Input::get('token'))->get();
```

Mas neste caso, eu preciso carregar o resultado no próprio objeto que efetuou a query. Algo assim:

```
$this = $sessao[0];
```

É claro que isso está fora de cogitação. :)
Outra opção seria:

```
$this->id     = $sessao[0]->id;
$this->token  = $sessao[0]->token;
```

E assim por diante. Talvez eu não tenha entendido muito bem como o Eloquent trabalha internamente no objeto. É possível realizar este carregamento de forma dinâmica?

Comment: @jorge-roberto Na verdade não é necessário retornar o objeto. Ao fazer a consulta podem acontecer duas coisas: o sessão pode ser encontrada (então ocorre o carregamento dos dados no mesmo objeto ), ou a sessão pode não ser encontrada  (e o objeto permanece sem carregamento). Para saber então se a sessão é válida ou não, criei um método público dentro da classe Sessao que verifica se o carregamento ocorreu ou não e responde um valor booleano.

Comment: Toda consulta que faz utilizando Eloquent retorna ou um Collection ou uma instância do próprio model. Acredito que a solução mais adequada é criar um método estático que retorne a primeira ocorrência com esse token.

Comment: Certo @VagnerdoCarmo. O modo que você sugeriu era o que eu costumava utilizar. Se não houver solução vou voltar a fazer dessa forma.

Answer (score 1):

Você quer retornar o objeto que tem o resultado da consulta após ter feita a consulta ? se for isso porque você não cria um método dentro do model:

```
public function SessionByToken($token){
 return Sessao::where('token',$token)->first();
}
```